# Iptables - boot

Tags: boot, iptables, persistence

Now that my iptables is pretty well configured, i think... Someone said to me that placing the script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables was not great.

What is the best solution for iptables to start before network-manager and any connection to the network ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Saving iptables as a script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables is not great probably because it's a bit *custom* method, however it's mentioned in Ubuntu's wiki.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration_on_startup

I personally recommend using `iptables-persistent`, as it's more reliable way of storing iptables rules. However it might be difficult to understand at the begging.

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
```

Your rules will be stored in:

- /etc/iptables/rules.v4 - IPv4 rules
- /etc/iptables/rules.v6 - IPv6 rules

You can save your current rules with:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/iptables-save.8.html

And to restore them use:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/iptables-restore.8.html

In Ubuntu there is however [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW). You may want to try it.

> The default firewall configuration tool for Ubuntu is ufw. Developed to ease iptables firewall configuration, ufw provides a user friendly way to create an IPv4 or IPv6 host-based firewall. By default UFW is disabled.

Comment: Thanks ! But i read that iptables-peristent wasn't maintained anymore ?

Comment: I do use iptables-save et restore without iptables-persistent. Iptables-persistent apply the rules at boot without the need for writing any script ?

Comment: And to someone of ask ubuntu : i totally forgot this post and created another, more complete. Could it be possible to merge the two, so i do not lose this answer, and the other ask ?

Comment: iptables-persistent is still maintained, you're probably found a fork of this package at github, but it's not same thing. And yes, it will apply iptables rules at boot, just try it and use `sudo iptables -vnL` after boot to check if your rules were applied properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However, how to make sure, to verify,  that iptables-persistent begin before the configuration of the interface by gnome network manager ?

Comment: How does iptables-persistent to better than a if-pre-up or a service ? Also, i post this while not remembering the first post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141464/iptables-rules-at-boot

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but it implies a few things: security should be like an onion - built with layers. You should not rely only on your iptables. When you can you should always have another device/router in front of your server that does firewall for you, i.e. linux box with vyos/vyatta or a edge router. When it comes to SSH you should also configure fail2ban, harden your SSH configuration (i.e. disallow passwords, use publickeys only, change default SSH port, or even use hosts.allow and hosts.deny) and so on.

Comment: And on your question: iptables commands are available even on early boot stage. but you can use `journalctl -b` to examine when netfilter is set and when your network is up. Note: you should rather look for `netfilter` strings in logs instead `iptables`. i.e. `May 08 02:10:11 hostname systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...`

Comment: Thanks. With grep i suppose, since as far as i remember, journalctl output is a lot of lines. I'll do that i soon as i can. And for the other post, the other solutions could work (i always have difficulties installing a package when a few lines of bash would suffice) ?

Comment: it's up to you to decide what works best for you. For me the way that iptables-persistent stores and apply rules is more reliable than bash scripts.

Comment: You must have reasons why you prefer it ? I admit i do not understand the difference between an application of the rules by a script or iptables-persistent, in the way they work, i mean.